# How to convert html as well as css content in pdf using Java?

Tags: java, itext, flying-saucer

I am getting NumberFormatException, how to parse css that is the border="1px solid black"??

```
try {
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(
              "/home/Booking_form_PDFs/booking_form.pdf"));
    document.open();
    HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
    String str = "<html><head></head><body>"
         + "<h1>Show your support</h1>"
         + "<table border=\"1px solid black\"><tr><td></td></tr></table>"
         + "</body></html>";
    htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(str));
    document.close();
    System.out.println("Done");
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1px solid black"at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1250) at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:452)
    at com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.CellWrapper.createPdfPCell(CellWrapper.java:132) at com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.CellWrapper.<init>(CellWrapper.java:87)at com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.createCell(HTMLWorker.java:475) at com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLTagProcessors$13.startElement(HTMLTagProcessors.java:409) at com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.startElement(HTMLWorker.java:199)
    at com.itextpdf.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.processTag(SimpleXMLParser.java:581)
    at com.itextpdf.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.go(SimpleXMLParser.java:299)
    at com.itextpdf.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.parse(SimpleXMLParser.java:607)
    at com.itextpdf.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.parse(HTMLWorker.java:153)
    at com.TrialHTMLtoPDF.main(TrialHTMLtoPDF.java:34)
```

Comment: None of this code parses numbers. Show the stacktrace, please

Comment: while parsing this "1px solid black"  it is giving number format exception, though added it in string @cricket_007

Comment: So, can we have the stacktrace?

Comment: stackTrace is as above..@cricket_007

Comment: Alright, thanks. Strange that a Float is trying to be parsed

Comment: it is not applying internal css, if you have written, it is showing that code in the generated pdf, though exception is not there.

Comment: What do you mean exception is not there and it is showing in pdf? Your code doesn't look like it runs to me

Comment: You are using the deprecated `HTMLWorker`. You should use `XMLWorker` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use escape like

`\"""` or `\"'"`

and use `+` in between if required

it is better you read it from a text file.
This would reduce this problem.

Comment: i already used escape character, do I need to type twice of it? Please write sample code for me, thanks already!

Comment: did you reading you css from text file. and see that css is properly syntaxes and formatted in your text file . And try single quote i.e  "<table border='1px solid black'><tr><td></td></tr></table>"

Comment: even this "<table border='1px solid black'><tr><td></td></tr></table>" isn't working

Comment: that is not requirement @Kishan C S

Comment: the only way to correct it as I have tried using jsoup or read it from text file

Comment: thanku @cricket_007 and Kishan, i have removed css and added only html

Comment: @Kishan Since the question does have escaped strings, you could show the process of reading a file in your answer

Answer (score 0):

The exception is raised because the HTML is not valid.

The table `border` attribute value is an integer, which gives the size of the border. For example :

```
<table border="1">...</table>
```

It is not possible to define the style or the color of the border with this attribute.

You should replace by CSS, as follow :

```
<table style="border:1px solid blue">...</table>
```

Comment: Thanks@obourgain, but while I was converting html to pdf it was not accepting css. That was the problem.